Recover data from a phone with a black screen. (Xiaomi Redmi 7)
I have a Xiaomi Redmi 7 with a black screen that i need to recover all the videos and photos in it, but all the options i saw i need to turn on the developer options in the phone, that its impossible because the tactile doesn´t works and the screen it´s completelly in black. The phone vibrates and emits a light so i know that woks but it have a password and the developer  options are off. It exits some way that i can recover all my data without change the screen or in this case its no other way? Thanks for the help
